# Messed up on the inverse of $\cosh(x)$ but I don't know where I went wrong

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

If someone can tell me where I went wrong, that would be extremely appreciated :)

> The function $f:[0,\infty)\mapsto[1,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=\cosh x$ is bijective. Find a formula for $f^{-1}.$

If $y=\cosh x$, then
\begin{align}
& y = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right) \\[5pt]
\implies & 2y = e^x+e^{-x} \\[5pt]
\implies & 2ye^x = e^x(e^x+e^{-x}) \\[5pt]
\implies & 2ye^x = e^{2x} + e^0 \\[5pt]
\implies & 2ye^x = e^{2x}+1 \\[5pt]
\implies & -e^{2x}+2ye^x - 1 = 0 \\[5pt]
\implies & e^x = \frac{-2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2-4(-1 \times -1)}}{-2} \\[5pt]
\implies & e^x = y + \sqrt{-2y+2} \text{ as $e^x>0$} \\[5pt]
\implies & x = \ln(y+\sqrt{-2y+2}) \\[5pt]
\implies & \cosh^{-1}x = \ln(y+\sqrt{-2y+2})
\end{align}

Comment: How did you go from $e^x=\dfrac{-2y\pm\sqrt{4y^2-4(-1)(-1)}}{-2}$ to $y\pm \sqrt{-2y+2}$. I find it is $y\mp \sqrt{y^2-1}$, and since $e^x$ is positive, we must have $e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2-1}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, don't use images. Learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and type your questions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo but, isn't $y-\sqrt{y^2-1}$ positive too? I think it is better to say we have $x=\ln(y\mp\sqrt{y^2-1})$ and since $x\in[0,\infty]$ then we should have $1<y\mp\sqrt{y^2-1}$ so we should consider the positive sign.

Comment: @Soheil Indeed you're absolutely right, that was a typo on my part. What I meant was that $x$ is non-negative by assumption, hence $x=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2-1})$ (i.e because we're trying to find the inverse to the function $\cosh:[0,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$). If instead we were trying to find the inverse for $\cosh:(-\infty,0]\to [1,\infty)$, then the inverse would be $x=\ln(y-\sqrt{y^2-1})$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
e^x &= \frac{-2y\pm\sqrt{(2y)^2-4}}{-2} \\[5pt]
&= \color{red}{y\pm\frac{\sqrt{4y^2-4}}{-2}} \\[5pt]
&= y\pm\frac{\sqrt{4}\sqrt{y^2-1}}{-2} \\[5pt]
&= y\pm \frac{2\sqrt{y^2-1}}{-2} \\[5pt]
&= y \mp\sqrt{y^2-1} \, .
\end{align}
Since $x$ is nonnegative, we know that $e^x \geq 1$. Hence, $y\mp\sqrt{y^2-1} \geq 1$. Notice that it has to be greater than or equal to $1$, not $0$ as you wrote in your question. Since $0<y-\sqrt{y^2-1}\leq 1$ for $y\geq1$, the negative branch doesn't work. Hence, $e^x=y\color{red}{+}\sqrt{y^2-1}$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=\cosh x$, then
\begin{align}
& y = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right) \\[5pt]
\implies & 2y = e^x+e^{-x} \\[5pt]
\implies & 2ye^x = e^x(e^x+e^{-x}) \\[5pt]
\implies & 2ye^x = e^{2x} + e^0 \\[5pt]
\implies & 2ye^x = e^{2x}+1 \\[5pt]
\implies & -e^{2x}+2ye^x - 1 = 0 \\[5pt]
\implies & e^x = \frac{-2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2-4(-1 \times -1)}}{-2} \\[5pt]
\color{red} \implies & \color{red}{e^x = y + \sqrt{-2y+2} \text{ as $e^x>0$}}\\[5pt]
\end{align}

Indeed you should get:

\begin{align}
\implies & e^x = y ±  (-1) \sqrt{y^2 -1} \\[5pt]
\end{align}

Then, following the justification given in the comments by Soheil, you can conclude that since $x \in [0,\infty)$, you end $$\cosh^{-1}(x)= \log(x + \sqrt{x^2-1})$$